# Unable to hide or remove views in UICollectionViewCell when using Autolayout

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UIImageView (lets call it *myImageView*) in a UICollectionViewCell with its bare necessary constraints in place. I am using storyboards and linking up the views and code with `viewWithTag`.

In cellForItemAtIndexPath, there is a condition whereby e.g.:

```
if (1 + 1 == 2)
    myImageView.hidden = YES;
else
    myImageView.hidden = NO
```

I have set breakpoints and verified that the code has been executed but the *myImageView* doesn't get hidden for the first batch of visible cells (assuming all of them have met the condition).

When I scroll down to reveal the new (or reused rather) cells, the everything works as expected (cells that met the condition and are suppose to be hidden are hidden, vice versa). It also works as expected when I scroll back up to reveal the first batch of cells again.

The problem only lies with the first batch of visible cells.

I have tried `removeFromSuperview` instead of hiding the cells but had no luck there too.

Is there a proper way or any best practices when working with autolayout and UICollectionViews in such situations?

Comment: Is the condition true before the first call to `cellForItemAtIndexPath` ?  It sounds like it is becoming true after the first cells have already been displayed and you haven't called reloadData

Comment: @Paulw11 I retrieve the data via an API. Retrieved from the API is an array of dictionaries, and the condition to hide that imageview is in that dictionary. I call reloadData after I've successfully retrieve the data from the API. Whether the imageview is initially hidden or not, it should update accordingly as per the if else condition, as I catered to both cases right?

Comment: It should.  Is there a particular reason you are using view tags instead of a custom cell class with IBOutlets?

Comment: @Paulw11 No particular reason. I tried creating a subclass of UICollectionViewCell just for this but got the same results. Either way, the code still went into the correct block for hiding or unhiding when it met or did not met the hide condition. I had an observation though, that if I check the hidden box for the imageview in storyboard, the same thing happens but opposite; imageviews that are suppose to be shown are hidden for the first batch of hidden cells.

Comment: So it sounds like your first cells are being rendered before the condition is set.  Make sure you are calling `reloadData` from inside the completion block of your fetch - perhaps show that code

Comment: @Paulw11 do you maybe have a suggestion that's more catered towards the auto layout side of things? Yep reloadData is in the completion block of my fetch. I'm actually updating an app for full auto layout support. It works before without autolayout but having this weird behaviour now. I got a feeling that somehow the constraints are still persisting for some reason.

Comment: Constraints shouldn't be anything to do with `.hidden`

Comment: @Paulw11 right! This has prompted me to drag a height constraint of the imageview as an IBOutlet to the UICollectionViewCell subclass and setting the constant to 0 instead of hiding. I will try this when I get back to my Mac later.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we can't set tags to constraints, we have no choice but to subclass UICollectionViewCell and link the constraint to an IBOutlet.

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
cell.imageViewHeightConstraint.constant = imageViewShouldHide ? 0 : cell.imageView.image.size.height;
```

Simply put, toggle the height constraint of the view between *n* value & *0*, instead of hidden between *YES* & *NO*.

When adopting autolayout, I learnt that we should stop thinking about frames and rects but I wasn't sure about hiding views. Thanks for the tip @Paulw11!